# Secure storage for android PhoneGap application

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We are developing a PhoneGap application for iOS and Android in which I ***need to store a small configuration variable securely*** **(Not LocalStorage, SQLite or any DB implementation)**. I know this can be done using the KeyChain feature of iOS. Please help me out in finding the similar feature in **android** or suggest any such Android PhoneGap plugin for Secure Storage to implement in our project.

Comment: I think there is a sqlite plugin with sqlcipher support, or you can look into the android keystore

Comment: @prodeveloper answers to this question are really funny..did u get a suitable plugin?

Comment: @Lakshay. No, stopped looking from then. Please suggest if you get any solid idea for implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalStorage. Documentation is [HERE](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

If you are looking for KeyChain Plugin, you can find it in [HERE](https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please note that I asked about the implementation in PhoneGap android.

Comment: Take a look at this one. http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.crypho.plugins.securestorage

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins available in Cordova/ PhoneGap to store data in the device itself. If you are building a native application then you can go for SQLite and if you are building a Hybrid mobile app then you can go for [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)  .

You can check what all browser's it supports over [here](http://pouchdb.com/learn.html#browser_support). (There he has stated in terms of the browser which Android/IOS/Windows makes use of).

Comment: I think it's not good to implement PouchDB for saving one very small configuration variable securely. Please rethink and suggest a better alternative

Comment: Sorry I thought you have to store complex data in your device, so suggested that. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

For securely saving key, password or string in mobile application especially in cordova/phonegap apps there is different approaches for different platforms.

- For iOS application we can use - [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)
- For android application we can use - [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)

There is plugin named - [cordova-plugin-secure-key-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-secure-key-store). This plugin uses Keychain for iOS and Keystore for android.

For more details follow blog post here - http://stackskull.com/posts/how-to-save-key-securely-in-mobile-devices

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: just to be clear, pradeep1991singh - is the author of above mentioned plugin. When i tried to use this plugin it thew `mutating method sent to immutable object` error on ios platform. Android works fine.

Answer (score -1):

**Use this plugin:** https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/161

> Note: a phonegap plugin is made of native code, i.e. here Android SDK Java code. This plugin use secured Keychain system. Phonegap plugins simply adds a JS/Java cross-code interface, making possible to call native features with javascript functions. Btw geolocation, notification and so third, in Phonegap doc, are working this way.

Comment: Yes, LocalStorage is insecure, that's why I asked about the native feature of Android SDK to store securely or any such implementation already done for PhoneGap you know.

Comment: @prodeveloper I have understood this way. So use the plugin I pointed in my answer https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/161
A plugin = (native Android SDK java code) + (cross-code JS/Java i/o) .   ==> this plugin provides what you need.

Comment: The URL you mentioned is a KeyChain Plugin for Cordova iOS. I am posted the question for Cordova Android platform. Please read carefully.